# Creating a stand-alone executable file for c++ code using Visual Studio express 2013

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, executable

I need to create a .exe for my project in visual studio express 2013. I have a form and is created to run multithreaded. The .exe file needs to run in a different computer. The project builds without error and runs perfectly. I've read threads that say that I need to change `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) to Multi-threaded (/MT)` in the properties -> c/c++ -> code generation -> runtime library to run the .exe file in a different computer. After I tried this when I build the project an error already occurs: "`Error   2   error D8016: '/clr' and '/MT' command-line options are incompatible".` Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

**EDIT**
I've tried creating a folder and added the .exe file (in /MD) together with the missing DLL file. I tried running the .exe file on the different computer then a different error occurs: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"

Comment: When you created the project you specified the wrong setting, you're using the .NET compiler instead of the native one.

Comment: @MarkRansom When I turn it back to /MD, the .exe will still not work to the other computer. Thus this mean that I have to install the  clr and the crt to the other computer where I want to run the .exe file?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you get a successful build, you *WILL* have "an .exe that can run on a different computer".
2. Visual Studio supports both "standard" C++, and C++/CLI, which allows .Net language extensions, and runs as .Net managed code.
3. Your /clr switch implies you're (perhaps inadvertently) building a C++/CLI program.
4. SUGGESTION: Disable CLR:

   C++ > General > "Compile with Common Language Runtime Support" > "No"
5. If your source contains any CLI extensions, the build should now fail, and you can substitute standard C++ equivalents.
6. Conversely, if you *want* a C++/CLI program - it should be able to run on any Windows PC with the appropriate .Net runtime.  Just turn off the "/MT" option (all .Net programs support multi-threading) and rebuild.

Comment: I changed the Compile with Common Language Runtime Support to "No" then 140 errors occured. 100 form intellisence errors and 40 from my namespaces.

Comment: @rocky you're probably trying to use .NET classes for your UI. If you don't intend to have a dependency on the .NET libraries and runtime, that was a mistake. You'll have to start over with a different technology such as MFC.

Comment: @MarkRansom are there any other options?

Comment: @rocky none that I'm aware of, but I don't have a lot of experience in that area. I consider the combination of C++ and .NET to be an abomination, if you want to go all in for .NET you should be using C#.

Comment: See [Deploying Native Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx)

Comment: I agree with Mark Ransom: if you want a .Net program, it would probably be easier to start from scratch in C# or VB.Net.  Otherwise, if you want a "native .exe", C/C++ is a good choice.  But then YOU MUST CREATE YOUR C/C++ PROJECT initially as a *Windows* project; not a .Net project.